# get key value from array within array in php laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I just want to get the value which is in array with in array.
Following is my array.

I have a variable called $checklist.

```
$checklist = Checklist::where('equipment_id', Input::get('id'))->get()->toArray();
```

when I var_dump($checklist) it gives the following result.

```
array (size=2)
0 => 
array (size=10)
'id' => string 'a953fd4a509b41e0b12a1385aef7bca9' (length=32)
'checklist_template_id' => string '5d9ef7a83a4943c9a9580fd22d1dae2a' (length=32)
'ordre_id' => string '8b3392e34ff545b488d6623b2a27e7f5' (length=32)
'equipment_id' => string 'a797d64908024babb7e1eb4fc9167b78' (length=32)
'status' => string '' (length=0)
'image' => string '' (length=0)
'comment' => string '' (length=0)
'deleted_at' => null
'created_at' => string '2016-02-12 11:33:45' (length=19)
'updated_at' => string '2016-02-12 11:33:45' (length=19)
1 => 
array (size=10)
'id' => string 'ba5e4e822e5c44ba96132a9f196dc896' (length=32)
'checklist_template_id' => string '5d9ef7a83a4943c9a9580fd22d1dae2a' (length=32)
'ordre_id' => string '8b3392e34ff545b488d6623b2a27e7f5' (length=32)
'equipment_id' => string 'a797d64908024babb7e1eb4fc9167b78' (length=32)
'status' => string '' (length=0)
'image' => string '' (length=0)
'comment' => string '' (length=0)
'deleted_at' => null
'created_at' => string '2016-02-12 10:16:19' (length=19)
'updated_at' => string '2016-02-12 10:16:19' (length=19)
```

All I want is, get "checklist_template_id" alone... how can I get it? can anyone help me with it???

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by looping your array as below

```
$result = array();
foreach($checklist as $key=> $val)
{
  $result[] = $val['checklist_template_id'];
}

print_r($result);
```

this should help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `array_column`

```
$checklist_template_ids = array_column($checklists, 'checklist_template_id');
```

If you which to index the resulting array by checklists id, so you can make something like `id => checklist_template_id` then simply include it as third argument like so

```
$checklist_template_ids = array_column($checklists, 'checklist_template_id', 'id');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve by using below example:

```
 $donor_details = array();
    $return_arr_1 = array();
       foreach ($donor_loc as $key=>$value)
                    {

                        $donor_details['name']=$value->full_name;
                        $donor_details['contact']=$value->contact_number;
                        $return_arr_1[] = $donor_details;
                    }
    print_r($return_arr_1 );
```